# Can upload / download files at Karate Driver?

Tags: driver, karate

When using KarateDriver, I want to upload and download files on the browser.

- Upload : Using `<input type="file" />`
- Download : Browser download. The response header is `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.txt`

But I don't know how to do it.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry we haven't implemented it yet. If you have some sample Selenium code we can take a look at that. Maybe we should open a feature request.

Comment: I will investigate it and send a pull request for KarateDriver, If I can resolve it.