# How can I upload a PDF file using Karate UI Automation?

Tags: user-interface, karate

Related the issue: [Can upload / download files at Karate Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329658/can-upload-download-files-at-karate-driver), Could you please help me to create the karate Ui code for upload excel PDF in this structure:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
                      <label>Faça o upload do seu arquivo</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="input-group-btn">
                          <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                            Browse...
                            <input id="file_input" name="file_input" type="file" style="display: none;" data-shinyjs-resettable-id="file_input" data-shinyjs-resettable-type="File" data-shinyjs-resettable-value="" class="shinyjs-resettable shiny-bound-input">
                          </span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No file selected" readonly="readonly">
                      </div>
                      <div id="file_input_progress" class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I tried to use this source code below without success:

```
* def uri = 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload'
    * def uploadSelector = '#file-upload'
    * def submitSelector = '#file-submit'

    # this function is for getting the full path of a file that is necessary to use with selenium sendKeys method when
    # a file. I agree with the fact that every folder in Karate would contain the files used within the feature. Nevertheless
    # having it results in a duplication of files if a lot of features use the same files. In this example I put the file in a
    # separate folder. Maybe a Karate builtin function for retrieving the full path of a file in this specific case would be
    # useful
    * def fullPathFile =
      """
            function(arg) {
             return Java.type('examples.Utility').getFullPath(arg);
            }
      """


  * def pdfFile = fullPathFile('files/pdf-test.pdf')

    Given driver uri
    And waitFor(uploadSelector).input(pdfFile)
    When submit().click(submitSelector)
    And delay(5000)
    Then match driver.text('#content > div > h3') == 'File Uploaded!'
    And match driver.text('#uploaded-files') contains 'pdf-test.pdf'
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: first read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61904351/143475 - because the Chrome native integration supports `driver.inputFile()` which is available in 0.9.6.RC4

File upload is a well-known hard problem to solve in browser automation. We will need some contributions from the community, but here is a demo I just experimented with using Karate Robot: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-robot

```
Feature:

Scenario:
* driver 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload'
* robot { app: '^Chrome', highlight: true }
* robot.click('choose-file.png')
* robot.input('/Users/pthomas3/Desktop')
* robot.input(Key.ENTER)
* robot.click('file-name.png')
* robot.input(Key.ENTER)
* delay(1000)
* click('#file-submit')
* delay(2000)
* screenshot()
```

You can see a video of the execution here: https://twitter.com/ptrthomas/status/1253373486384295936

The other options I can think of:

a) Use Karate's API testing capabilities to perform a `multipart` file upload: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-file - this is actually in most cases sufficient  to "complete" the flow you have. For example for this exact same flow you see above, it looks like this:

```
* url 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload'
* multipart file file = { read: 'billie.png', filename: 'billie.png', contentType: 'image/png' }
* method post
```

And typically you may need to add a cookie or two, which you can easily pass from [the browser](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#cookie) to the [API test / HTTP client](https://github.com/intuit/karate#cookie).

b) The other option is something I haven't tried yet, you can "fake" the part of the UI that does the file-upload and replace it with something else, if it can get you forward in your flow. Refer this: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1248996522357739521