# Can you help me in figuring out a way for upload a file in karate ui?

Tags: karate

my use case:
I have a  upload button, when i click upload button it opens file-explorer and asks for file to upload

i was not able to figure out how to upload  in karate ui.Can some one help me how to upload a file in karate ui?

Currently i am using the latest version 0.9.6.Rc4.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61393515/143475 - mods please close this